# When you Ctrl+C a block of content from MS Word, what kind of structure does it have?

Tags: ms-word, clipboard, wysiwyg, copy-paste

I'm interested in finding out what kind of format the data takes when placed inside the clipboard. This is because I need to develop a kind of WYSIWYG editor that accepts pasted data from MS Word, and I want to keep the original formatting if possible. That includes tables and bullet points. Does Microsoft have any documentation on this?

I'm coding on PHP, btw.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN > Desktop > Learn > Reference > Windows Application UI Development > Data Exchange > Clipboard > Clipboard Overviews > Clipboard Formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649013%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) [emphasis mine]:

> Many applications work with data that cannot be translated into a
>   standard clipboard format without loss of information. These
>   applications can create their own clipboard formats. A clipboard
>   format that is defined by an application, is called a registered
>   clipboard format. **For example, if a word-processing application copied
>   formatted text to the clipboard using a standard text format, the
>   formatting information would be lost. The solution would be to
>   register a new clipboard format**, such as Rich Text Format (RTF).

There are a lot more details on that page.

Comment: As an aside: are you talking about a web app (since you mention PHP)? If so, you can't really see the clipboard in its "native" form.

Answer (score 1):

If you are coding a WYSIWYG editor, then that will (almost certainly) be done in Javascript, and you won't have to worry about how the formatted text from Microsoft Word is represented before it is pasted, because you will not have access to this anyway.

You will, however, need to worry about how it is represented in HTML once the user presses paste, and the browser requests and processes this and pastes the result into the ContentEditable/DesignMode element as HTML nodes.

To a large extent, how well it is formatted in HTML is dependent on how well it was formatted in Word.  As we know, it is easy to be non-semantic in Word, by using the font size drop-down instead of altering paragraph styles, by using bullet characters rather than actual bulleted or numbered lists, etc.  If you depend on bulletted lists becoming proper HTML unordered lists, you will need to hope that whoever added them in Word added them using the list function, or you will have extra complicated processing to do otherwise.

The end result may also be influenced by which browser the user is using, whether it's in quirks mode, and which version of Word they are using.  Also, the same document opened in OpenOffice will paste differently into HTML in the browser.  You will need to use a general-purpose HTML filter and sanitiser, server-side.

In addition, you will probably want to filter out the following, at a minimum, from the resultant HTML (unless you are interested in preserving any custom style the user added, regardless of its appropriateness for the web):

- IE-specific conditional comments.  Sometimes these end up in the resulting HTML
- Any inline styles, including the `style=` attribute, `<style>` elements, etc.

Comment: Well, what kind of format will the pasted text take? That is what I am interested in. As of now, I have no idea how to even begin parsing the pasted text.

Comment: It's be part of the page's DOM.  Once you grab it with, say, .innerHTML, it'll be HTML.  How are you at Javascript?  Are you going to use an existing rich text control or write one in Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

There will be more than a dozen formats to choose from. Text, RTF, HTML, and OLE are the major ones.  There will also be stupid formats such as Bitmap, which are rendered on-the-fly using delayed rendering.